# Please help..I cant seem to figure this out.. JS issue

Tags: javascript, lightbox

So Ive been trying to make this basic(or so i thought) site. page opens up with a picture and some thumbs below it.. you click on a thumb and the opening pic disappears and the clicked thumbnail lightboxes a picture in the middle of the page..easy right??? Works amazing until I uploaded it to the server..now I cant get it to work and cant figure it out..can someone please visit the site and see what Im doing wrong? my JS ability is sketchy so Im sure its got something to do with that.

The site is  www. markdektor . com

no spaces.. please help.

Comment: Hi Noah. You are getting all the downvotes because you simply said "I can't get it to work" and posted a link. When posting a question please describe exactly what the nature of the error is, preferably include the code you suspect is not working. Also, include information on what you have tried doing to fix it. Following these steps will help us help you, increase the quality of the question and reduce the number of downvotes you seem to be getting.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried being more specific..but honestly I cant figure out whats making it not wortk.. Seems like Ive checked and double checked ..\

Answer (score 0):

It looks like none of you scripts are being loaded, either they are in the wrong place or you've got something in place to redirect failed requests to a 404 page. Is there something like a .htaccess file missing that wasn't uploaded?

Edited: If you do not have a .htaccess file (or NginX config), then you may need one if you are using a framework. Considering that direct access brings me to a custom 404 page, I am going to assume you are using some sort of framework. I will also assume that you are using Apache on the server, but I admit I could be wrong, it's just a guess. Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I dont think so.. I uploaded the entire folder and made sure everything was theer.. like i said it seems to work fine before I put it on the server...thought maybe it was a case sensitivity issue..

Comment: When I try to visit http://www.markdektor.com/js, I get a 404 page. So either they are truly not there or there is something Apache/NginX/etc that is preventing the browser from finding them where they are located.

Comment: ok...I appreciate the comments..think this is helping..but how do I add the above to a .htaccess file?

Comment: hmm... Well, I have added the files...except for the htaccess file... so I know that they are they..what would possibly be keeping it from working? i believe it has Apache..its hosted on godaddy.

Comment: Put it in the site's root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Firefox with Firebug installed. It gives me several 404's. Are you sure the paths to your js and css files are correct? Here is Firebug console output that sugges that your paths aren't correct:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.markdektor.com/css/normalize.css" normalize.css 

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.markdektor.com/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js" modern....min.js 

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.markdektor.com/js/plugins.js" plugins.js 

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.markdektor.com/js/main.js" main.js 

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.markdektor.com/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js" modern....min.js 

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.markdektor.com/js/plugins.js" plugins.js 

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.markdektor.com/js/main.js" main.js 

TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function      
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In the future, when your JS doesn't work please start by using Firefox with Firebug or any other browser with it's dev console to at least do cursory troubleshooting.

Comment: Ive tried that. I inspected the element. . it looks like my JS folder isnt there and one of my css files is missing...but they are there.. again..its wierd that it would work just fine but then when i go live with it, it breaks.

Comment: one of the missing files on the above list is: `http://www.markdektor.com/js/main.js`. When I try to go to it, I get a 404. This is a static file. Whats more likely: that the server is just ignoring static files and is wrong? or that you put the files in the wrong place or your paths are wrong? Chances are You are wrong.

Comment: I will go back and check it.. thank you very much. Ill try to be more concise next time. I'm new to the site.

Comment: Im still having the issue.. Ive inspected the element and it keeps showing me errors in my custom.js file.. like its pointing to something thats just not there in the code. is there any chance you could look at it again and see if you have any suggestions.